# Is there a way to generate picture of component of JFrame over transparent background not JFrame itself?

Tags: java, swing, netbeans-8, paintcomponent

I have a method which takes file path and file name to save picture of current form. but the problem is, i want it to save components of frame only not with frame background. I m really beginner so can anyone help me ?

```
public void save(String imageFile, String path) throws InterruptedException {
        Rectangle r = getBounds();

        try {
            BufferedImage i = new BufferedImage(r.width,r.height,
            BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
            Graphics g = i.createGraphics();//getGraphics();
            paintComponents(g);
            ImageIO.write(i, "png", new File(imageFile,path));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: You can paint any Swing component to an image. Just invoke the paint() or print() method of the component you want to paint.

Comment: First, you should be using `printAll`, not `paintComponent`.  Second, if you want a transparent background, you need to make the component transparent (`setOpaque(false)`) - just don't forget to reset when you're done

Comment: It is not allowing me to change setOpaque value of jframe false. does it has anythog to do with my system ?    i tried but setOpsque method does not exist so tried `setOpacity(0)`, it gives "TRANSLUCENT translucency is not supported." error. im using ubuntu with netbeans 8 and jdk 8  if it helps.

Comment: @SaugatPoudel, The suggestion was to make the component opaque, not the frame. I'm not sure I'm understanding what you are trying to do. Post an [mre] demonstrating the problem and indicate where your transparent background is.

Comment: [example](https://postimg.cc/WhSW6qDP). If you look at that picture, it has transparent background. What i want is to create a .png of components inside jFrame with similar transparent background.

Comment: [what i want](https://postimg.cc/WhSW6qDP) vs [what is happening](https://postimg.cc/N9jPTXTK)

Comment: If addition to all the above comments you need to use: `BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB` to allow for transparent images. Without a proper [mre] we can't offer any further help.